# ESLint with Prettier issues on Yarn global install

Tags: eslint, yarnpkg, prettier

I'm in the process of setting up my ReactJS environment, and I'm following the FrontendMasters course on the topic.

After having installed **eslint** and **prettier** globally via Yarn, the author runs this command `eslint js\**\*.{js,jsx}` and on his machine, all is good, but I get the following:

> Oops! Something went wrong! :(
>
> ESLint couldn't find the plugin "eslint-plugin-prettier". This can happen for a couple different reasons:
>
> 1. If ESLint is installed globally, then make sure eslint-plugin-prettier is also installed globally. A globally-installed ESLint cannot find a locally-installed plugin.
> 2. If ESLint is installed locally, then it's likely that the plugin isn't installed correctly. Try reinstalling by running the following:
>
>    npm i eslint-plugin-prettier@latest --save-dev
>
> If you still can't figure out the problem, please stop by https://gitter.im/eslint/eslint to chat with the team.

I tried Google, but couldn't find anything relevant. Why is this happening? I am on Windows 10, using the latest version of Yarn (v0.24.6) and my `eslintrc.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "extends": ["airbnb", "prettier", "prettier/react"],
  "plugins": ["prettier"],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2016,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    }
  },
  "env": {
    "es6": true,
    "browser": true,
    "node": true
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I followed Daydream's advice below, though I do not have `nvm` installed. But I did delete the `node_modules` folder, and after a chat in ESLint's Gitter, I went ahead and uninstalled `ESLint`, and `Prettier` globally. I then made `ESLint` and `Prettier` **devDependencies**. Finally I ran `yarn` command to reinstall everything, and now I get this:

[image]

**Note**: The project is open source, and is [on GitHub](https://github.com/Ciwan1859/LyricsZest-Frontend) if you want to see for yourself.

Comment: I assume you intended to tag Yarn the package manager, rather than YARN the Apache project?

Comment: sorry, yes @halfer

Comment: I have the same issue, after adding the .eslintrc.json shown at https://btholt.github.io/complete-intro-to-react-v4/eslint-prettier. Have you found a solution?

Comment: I have not sadly :(

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same issue myself. It appears to be an issue with the newest version of eslint, mine was 4.2.0. To fix this I:

```
    run: Yarn remove eslint
or
    run: npm uninstall eslint
```

this will remove it locally, then

```
    run: yarn add eslint@3.19.0 
or  run: npm install eslint@3.19.0

    run: eslint **/*.{js,jsx} --quiet
```

my paths may be set up different so do this in conjunction with "Daydream Nation" answer you should get it working. I'm not sure what version os eslint Brian is using and I'm sure if you pull down one of his most recent repo's it will tell you but hopefully this will guide you in the right direction.

Comment: I should also mention if you play the Frontend Master video ESLint further you will notice other people are having the same issue and you will notice he is also using eslint@3.19.0

Comment: I am using `3.19.0`, and still get the same issue. And yep I did notice one guy tell him about the same issue.

Comment: Also tried the path change as suggested by @DaydreamNation, but still get the exact same error about `cannot find module eslint-config-prettier/react`

Answer (score 0):

I was missing several packages. Here is how I fixed it.

```
npm i eslint-config-prettier -save-dev
npm i eslint-config-standard -save-dev
npm i eslint-plugin-node -save-dev
npm i eslint-plugin-promise -save-dev
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "rpp-react",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "meteor run"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-runtime": "^6.20.0",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "~0.2.4",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-addons-pure-render-mixin": "^15.6.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^2.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^8.0.0",
    "eslint": "^4.7.2",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^2.5.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^10.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^2.35.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^2.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.0.1",
    "prettier": "^1.7.0"
  }
}
```

Here is my .eslintrc.json

```
{
  "extends": [
    "standard",
    "plugin:flowtype/recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "prettier",
    "prettier/flowtype",
    "prettier/react",
    "prettier/standard"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "flowtype",
    "react",
    "prettier",
    "standard"
  ],
  "parserOptions": {
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    }
  },
  "env": {
    "es6": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": "error"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an **UGLY HACK**, but it was the ONLY WAY for me... to solve this problem.
I used "strace" tool to check what modules are required, i copied that files (pacience in this step please!) and it worked :)

```
strace eslint --debug Person.js
```

Yes... you have to scroll some lines until you found something like this:

**stat("/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/eslint/node_modules/eslint-plugin-prettier", 0x7fff5c139db0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)**

You need to COPY that required modules... and it will work.

These are a list of modules that i had to copy manually (inside /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/eslint/node_modules/)

```
eslint-config-airbnb
eslint-config-airbnb-base
eslint-plugin-import
eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y
eslint-plugin-prettier
eslint-plugin-prettier/node_modules/fast-diff
eslint-plugin-react
```

Please excuse my ugly english, i'm learning :)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error ("cannot find module eslint-config-prettier/react") while following the [steps](https://btholt.github.io/complete-intro-to-react-v4/eslint-prettier#eslint) from the Frontend Masters course you mention and was able to resolve it by installing [eslint-config-prettier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-prettier), as shown below, before running the lint script:

```
npm install --save-dev eslint-config-prettier
```

or, if using yarn:

```
yarn add --dev eslint-config-prettier
```

Note that eslint-config-prettier "turns off all rules that are unnecessary or might conflict with prettier".

Answer (score 0):

For me it happened after I (intentionally) uninstalled "eslint-plugin-prettier", and forgot to remove "prettier" from the "plugins" array in my eslint config, like so:

package.json:

```js
{
  // ...
  "eslintConfig": {
    // ...
    "plugins": [
      // ...
      // This needed to be removed
      "prettier"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm also doing the course, and the first tip I saw on the web was to reference the direct path to eslint via the installation by yarn into node_modules:

`./node_modules/.bin/eslint **/*.{js,jsx} --quiet`

But then after that, I was met with an error message with `- Unexpected top-level property "ecmaFeatures"`

Ultimately, what I did to solve the problem was to erase node_modules, erase everything from`~/.nvm/versions/node/<the version>/lib/node_modules` **except for** the `npm` and `yarn` folders, and just typed `yarn` to re-install everything.

After that,`./node_modules/.bin/eslint **/*.{js,jsx} --quiet` worked fine (but I still had to specify the path to the installation.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I don't have `nvm` installed, but I did delete `node_modules`, see updated question.

Comment: Try `./node_modules/.bin/eslint **/.*{js|jsx} --quiet`

Later on when running webpack, he calls it in a similar way (basically you are calling the one installed in 'node_modules' when you ran yarn for the first time)